# Error memory-mapping a file: Array can't be memory-mapped: Python objects in dtype

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

My application needs to store and access a very large matrix. I though I would use dok_matrix for this, but I can't seem to be able to memory-map the file. I get the error: *Array can't be memory-mapped: Python objects in dtype.*

Here is the code:

```
def __init__(self, ratings_file):

    try:
        self.ratings = np.load(ratings_file, mmap_mode='r+')
        self.n_users = self.ratings.shape[0]
        self.n_items = self.ratings.shape[1]
    except IOError:
        self.ratings = None
        self.n_users = 0
        self.n_items = 0

def add_ratings(self, ratings):
    # update the number of users and items
    self.n_users = max(self.n_users, max([r[0] for r in ratings]) + 1)
    self.n_items = max(self.n_items, max([r[1] for r in ratings]) + 1)

    # reshape (or create) the matrix
    if not self.ratings:
        self.ratings = dok_matrix((self.n_users, self.n_items), dtype=np.dtype(np.float32))
    else:
        self.ratings.resize((self.n_users, self.n_items))

    print 'Num. users: ', self.n_users
    print 'Num. items: ', self.n_items

def update_model(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()

def save(self):
    np.save(self._ratings_file, self.ratings)
```

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the line 
    self.ratings = dok_matrix((self.n_users, self.n_items), dtype=np.dtype(np.float32))
why is `type` equal to this compound thing as opposed to just `np.float32`? Aren't you just trying to say you want a matrix of floats?